# Can't connect 2nd swipe gesture in interface builder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder, gesture

I'm trying to add two gestures to a UIView in interface builder (swipe left and swipe right).

The first one (swipe left) works ... but the 2nd swipe gesture (swipe right) doesn't work, and I think it's because I can't connect the "New Referencing Outlet Connection" to the view (like my 1st gesture has) [see attached image].

[image: can't connect outlet collection]

Is this the reason?

I achieve this programatically, but would really like to understand how to add multiple gestures in interface builder.

Comment: Wait, that's what the Referencing Outlet Collection Connection does??? +1

Answer (score 0):

Look at the connections menu. They both automatically get added to the gestureRecognizers collection.

Answer (score 0):

I made a short tutorial video on how to use multiple gestures (right and left) in the interface builder. No coding is needed. I think a video is a better explanation for you :)
My english is not the best, but I hope it helps you! :)

[Xcode connect multiple gestures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFZir9SYDC8)